# VBA Loop Worksheet Filter Using Multiple Variables

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to provide a easy search tab for some of my employees in order for them to easily filter through a large data table for specific entries and then copy the row from the master list and past into search tab.

The code below actually works and copies the data from the entries that match, unfortunately "country" is the only criteria that works and the rest do nothing.

What I am trying to do is tweak the code I have written to get all criteria to work and if the criteria is blank in the corresponding search then it ignores that criteria allowing any value in that cell to be copy and pasted. I was thinking adding If Else statements for all of the criteria would do the job but I'm not exactly sure how to properly add If Else statement in VBA for all the strings and tell it to ignore the criteria if it is blank.

```html
Sub search_and_extract_multicriteria()

Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'where is the data copied from
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet 'where is the data pasted to
Dim country As String
Dim SubType As String
Dim ProductName As String
Dim ProductFormula As String
Dim Source As String
Dim Rating As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'row counter

Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set reportsheet = Sheet3
country = reportsheet.Range("A3").Value
SubType = reportsheet.Range("C3").Value
ProductName = reportsheet.Range("D3").Value
ProductFormula = reportsheet.Range("E3").Value
Source = reportsheet.Range("F3").Value
Rating = reportsheet.Range("G3").Value

reportsheet.Range("A16:K500").ClearContents 

datasheet.Select
'finalrow = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row

For i = 2 To 500 'finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = country And Cells(i, 3) = SubType And Cells(i, 4) = ProductName And Cells(i, 5) = ProductFormula And Cells(i, 6) = Source And Cells(i, 2) = TestimonialType And Cells(i, 9) = Rating Then 
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Copy 'copy columns 1 to 11 (A to K)
        reportsheet.Select 
        Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 
        datasheet.Select 
        End If
Next i

reportsheet.Select 'this is so that the report sheet is selected when the procedure ends

End Sub
```

Comment: To check if a string is blank I usually use `If not IsNull(string) and string <> "" Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a loop, how about just using the built in `AutoFilter` method after checking that the variable is populated with an actual value.

```
With datasheet.Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(500, 11))

    If Len(country) Then .AutoFilter 1, country
    If Len(TestimonialType) Then .AutoFilter 2, TestimonialType
    If Len(SubType) Then .AutoFilter 3, SubType
    If Len(ProductName) Then .AutoFilter 4, ProductName
    If Len(ProductFormula) Then .AutoFilter 5, ProductFormula
    If Len(Source) Then .AutoFilter 6, Source
    If Len(Rating) Then .AutoFilter 9, Rating

    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'offset 1 to remove header row
    reportsheet.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    .AutoFilter 'reset filter

End With
```

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately when I use the AutoFilter as you provided it only returns the header row of the datasheet with no other matching entries being displayed even after I created a entry specifically to be triggered. Any ideas? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MarkBellinger - did you test the code line-by-line to see what may be happening?

Comment: it looks like Len(country) is searching specifically for the word "country" and not the variable that is chosen in the assigned cell from a drop down of countries available as implemented in my original code. Is there a way to amend the code you gave me to take into account dynamic search strings as defined in a specific cell (as done in the original code) and take into account null values where the code should skip that filter. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize your code works great! the strings where trying to pull values from the wrong cells so it was performing exactly as it was supposed to. I update string locations in the code and it works perfect.

Comment: @MarkBellinger - glad you got it working :) please mark as answered so others know going fwd

Comment: Last question for you before I close this. The macro kinda works on Mac. It looks like the .AutoFilter does not work to clear the filters on the datasheet. It still appears to be copying the appropriate ranges to the reportsheet though.

Comment: @MarkBellinger ... try `.AutoFilterMode = False` or `.ShowAllData`. Can't remember which will work on `Mac` so you may need to research a bit if those doen't help.

Comment: In case anyone ever reads this I did get the .autofilter to work on mac to remove all filters on the target sheet by using ActiveSheet.ShowAllData